# Problem with ubuntu / W8 install and grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I recently made a mistake when installing Ubuntu 14.04 on an external hard drive plugged to a Windows 8.1 laptop. My problem is that now if I have the external hard-drive plugged I can choose on which OS I want to boot from a grub menu. But if the external hard-drive isn't plugged i have a grub terminal but no menu.

Is there a way to change that, so when the external hard-drive isn't plugged i can still boot to my w8 install?

Comment: Install Ubuntu on the hard drive?

Comment: I don't see how that would help me. i need Ubuntu on the external HD and yet grub menu to be functional when the external HD is not plugged in.

Comment: right, install ubuntu on the main hdd and it will install grub as well.

Comment: That's not an option for me. I installed Ubuntu on the external HD because it was the only place i could do it. Isn't there some kind of program i could launch on a live usb to install only grub on the main HD et have it configured to take into account both HD ? By the way thank-you for the answers ;-)

Comment: Maybe use the live usb to install grub?